# Cannot use session variable even if session has been started in php

Tags: php, session

I want to transfer data from one php page to other, and i used session to transfer it. I have started the session by using session_start() on both the pages.

```
    Page 1 : session_start();
             $x=10;
             $_SESSION['val']=$x;
    Page 2 : session_start();
             $value=$_SESSION['val'];
```

The Error pops out saying Undefined index:val . Please help, and explain why is this happening as i need to transfer data .

Comment: Well, this exactly piece of code should work. Must have something else.

Comment: Do you use cookie based sessions? If not, the session id parameter might be missing in the URL of the second page. That's a wild guess, though.

Comment: are you running the pages in CLI, or through a web server? are you running them on the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

try isset() !

isset() function in PHP determines whether a variable is set and is not NULL. It returns a Boolean value, that is, if the variable is set it will return true and if the variable value is null it will return false.

```
<?php

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['val']))
{

 $value=$_SESSION['val'];
//other code
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

session_start() statement must be at the top of page ( first line of code )

For Example :

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Comment: it definitely does not have to be the first line of code.